# c# - Как вставить изображение в ячейку excel?

Tags: c#, excel

У меня есть изображение, хранится как ресурс в приложении. Что можно использовать, чтобы добавить изображение в ячейку? Просто взять картинку и вставить её не получается... мб есть какие-нибудь функции о которых я не знаю. Использую библиотеку Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

Comment: Sheet.Shapes.AddPicture плюс поискать на en so готовые вопросы-ответы: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+image+into+cell+excel - а также обратите внимание, что точно в ячейку вставить не получится, изображение добавляется на лист.